# Gtk3 Popover outside the window

Tags: menu, gtk, popover, gtk3, gnome-shell

How can i make [Popover](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkPopover.html) appears outside application window like menu in gnome-shell panel? Or should i use another GTK widget?

[image: gnome-shell panel popup menu]

Comment: If I recall correctly, this is a limitation of GTK+; sorry.

Comment: @andlabs But how gnome-shell panel works?

Comment: Gnome-shell isn't GTK. It renders the desktop, so it can draw outside of windows if it likes.

Comment: @ptomato, I [dig](https://github.com/GNOME/gnome-shell/blob/edc445c0c94ece4e325c2127abffc0ea8cdafcbc/js/ui/popupMenu.js) [in](https://github.com/GNOME/gnome-shell/blob/edc445c0c94ece4e325c2127abffc0ea8cdafcbc/js/ui/boxpointer.js) [source](https://github.com/GNOME/gnome-shell/blob/edc445c0c94ece4e325c2127abffc0ea8cdafcbc/src/st/st-bin.c), and think that Gnome-shell uses Clutter as container for GTK Widget. I [made undecorated transparent window](https://i.imgur.com/6BmB4Mq.png) with [this stack](http://pastebin.com/WSDW70ux), but still not found good method for embedding gtk widget.

Comment: I believe on Wayland GtkPopovers can go beyond the window though.

Comment: Exactly, this is an X11 implementation limitation  one of GTK+.
There could easily be a workaround, but nobody has implemented it and all manpower now goes to wayland.

Comment: On sway, it appears that popovers can go beyond the window, but then they do not receive any mouse events :/

Comment: So necro. Much post

Comment: There is no "necro" when it comes to useful information. People update old content all the time - see wikipedia. You don't need to tell others about that br. - many old answers can still be partially correct but simply require more information to work. Perhaps things have changed in GTK4 now, I would not be surprised.

Answer (score 1):

This should be possible (at least on wayland).
gtk_popover_set_constrain_to (GtkPopover *popover,
GtkPopoverConstraint constraint);
"GTK_POPOVER_CONSTRAINT_NONE"

and

gtk_popover_set_pointing_to (GtkPopover *popover,
const GdkRectangle *rect);